# HAVING CLAUSE LIMITATION

Tags: sql

I'm working on a SQL code for my work, so I will make the question general.

When I use a count function, in my having clause, I've set the condition as

```
COUNT(ED.TRANSACTION_KEY) > QP.MIN_OCCURRENCES.
```

I've passed both ED and QP tables. It seems if I change the condition to `COUNT(ED.TRANSACTION_KEY) > 3`, the code works. However, once I set the conditions based on two parameters, the system shows "not a GROUP BY expression". Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use an aggregation function:

```
HAVING COUNT(ED.TRANSACTION_KEY) > MIN(QP.MIN_OCCURRENCES)
```

or move `QP.MIN_OCCURRENCES` to the `GROUP BY` clause.